# Java UserGenerator (output of 1000 datas)

Tags: java, generator

I want to write a UserGenerator in Java. I have to output 1000 Usernames/Passwords in a table format. Any one an idea?

[image]

Comment: You should not be storing the passwords as clear text.  Instead, hash the passwords using a salt, and store the hashed versions with the salt for each user.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Do you want to store them in a data base table or excel or text file? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't understand your need much but still wrote a quick program for you.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String username = "test" + i;
        String password = "password" + i;
        String email = "test" + i + "@test.com";
        String firstName = "test".toUpperCase() + i;
        String lastName = "test".toLowerCase() + i;

        System.out.println(username + ", " + password + "," + email + "," + firstName + "," + lastName);
    }

}
```

}

OUTPUT -

```
USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
test0, password0,test0@test.com,TEST0,test0
test1, password1,test1@test.com,TEST1,test1
test2, password2,test2@test.com,TEST2,test2
test3, password3,test3@test.com,TEST3,test3
test4, password4,test4@test.com,TEST4,test4
```